# Firebug not displayed while launching Firefox through selenium webdriver on eclipse Mars IDE.

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver, firebug

Firebug not displayed while launching Firefox through selenium webdriver on eclipse Mars IDE. While same is visible on launching Firefox manually without IDE.
Tried installing older version of Firefox still doesn't work.
Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont work like that.

Selenium creates a fresh profile every time so you will not get any cookies, form data and any plugin or add-on, which you have installed on your local browser.

You can achieve what you want by using [FirefoxProfile](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html)

- Load the Default Firefox Profile. This will load your default Firefox Profile along will all the data,extensions, history etc
- Or. If you just want to add The Firebug Extension. Then use the [`addExtension`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html#addExtension-java.io.File-) method of Firefox Profile